# Can rabbitmq suggest prefetch/QoS value based on its metrics?

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ allows QoS.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

The question is more about the optimal values. 
Can RabbitMQ propose optimal on its metrics value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. However, you can estimate it based on your use case.

I suggest you read this blog post from CloudAMQP: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-12-29-part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html

This is really well written and provides a lot of useful advice. In their section "How to set correct prefetch value?" they describe three cases:

- Single/few consumers and short processing time: `prefetch ~= round_trip / processing_time`
- Many consumers and short processing time: `prefetch < round_trip / processing_time`
- Many consumers and long processing time: `prefetch` set to 1